# Polynomial division - Bézout's theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

Consider the equation $(x^3-3x^2+4x-2)s(x)+(x^2-1)t(x)=x+1$. How can we find polynomials $s(x), t(x)$ which satisfy this equation?

Clearly $x+1$ divides the term involving $t(x)$ but not the first polynomial. If there are solutions then we need $(x+1)$ to divide $s(x)$. I am not sure where to go from here though.

Comment: You would need the degree of t to be one higher than the degree of s if they existed,  because you would need to cancel out the highest degree terms

Comment: There is no such polynomial because $x-1$ is a factor of the cubic polynomial.

Comment: Did you mean the equation ... $=x\color{red}-1$?  Then the answer would be $s(x)=\frac15$ and $t(x)=-\frac15(x-3)$

Comment: By the proofs in the linked dupe it is solvable $\iff$ their gcd $\,x-1\mid x+1\iff x+1\mid 2,\,$ contradiction (eval at $\,x=-1\,$ or compare degrees). Note that the proof I give their works in any Euclidean domain since then we have a Bezout equation for the gcd. In particular it works for polynomials over a field (here).

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$x^3-3x^2+4x-2=2(x-1)\Bigl(x^2-2x+2\Bigr)$$
Put $$s(x)=(x+1)R(x)$$
then

$$(x-1)\Bigl((x^2-2x+2)R(x)+t(x)\Bigr)=1$$
which is impossible.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs.